# Create a grouped tableview with gradient on its border

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uikit, core-animation, core-graphics

I need to create a grouped tableview with gradient on its border (not on its cells).
I made some research on the web but I'm not sure I understand how to proceed.
A little help could really unblock me in my project :).

Thanks

Comment: I have found something here: http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html , But what I really want is do the same effect on the borders (shadow/gradient) but without using an image (I need to manage different sizes, so it need to be programmaticaly).

Comment: Do you have an image that would show the effect that you are going for? I am having a hard time picturing it. It would appear that simply drawing a gradient to the UITableView's background is not what you are striving for. Thanks.

Comment: Check out these tutorials: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2033/core-graphics-101-lines-rectangles-and-gradients http://www.raywenderlich.com/2079/core-graphics-101-shadows-and-gloss http://www.raywenderlich.com/2106/core-graphics-101-arcs-and-paths